# Calculated Fields on Power BI with Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: powerbi, azure-devops

I'm looking at Power BI together with Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) in order to create some dashboards.

Is it possible to create a calculated field? Basically what I'm trying to get is:

Count of Resolved Bugs Today **minus** Count of Created Bugs Today

I can't even seem to find a way of filtering dates by today - in Team Services you can use the `@today` parameter - is there something similar?

I can see there are some pre-defined calculated fields, but how do I create my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any way to create your own field for now. You can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

And some information about Power BI data model for VSTS: [What's available in the Power BI connector for VSTS](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/report/vso-pbi-whats-available-vs)

The marcos like "@today", "@project" is only available in VSTS environment. You cannot use it in other environment.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. Seems a bit limiting that you can't do any sort of grouping/aggregate functions. I'm looking at using the VSO rest API to get data and pushing up a custom dataset to Power BI